# Gradle and Gradle wrapper versions

Tags: gradle, gradlew, versions

Can I have Gradle of version 2.10 and inside the `build.gradle` define a wrapper of version 3.0?

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = "3.0"
}
```

Comment: Yes, why not? Have you even tried it?

Comment: I was trying to change only that property in `build.gradle` and it was not seeing it. So I thought there might be impossible to have a wrapper of later version than the installed Gradle.
Finally I added the line
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.0-all.zip`
in my `gradle-wrapper.properties` and it seems to be fine.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configuration in `build.gradle` just has influence for the `wrapper` task. It will create the wrapper configuration with this version if you execute `gradle wrapper`.

Alternatively you can just change the version directly in the `gradle-wrapper.properties` as you did.